# I have one Excel sheet with multiple tabs, need to insert this data into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have one Excel file which contains multiple sheets. Every sheet name is the same as a table name in SQL Server. I need to insert data of these Excel sheets into respective tables in database.

There are 13 tabs and 13 tables in SQL server DB.

I am able to insert one sheet's data to one table with the code below.

```
String strConnection = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=<>;Integrated Security=True";

String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath);

// Create Connection to Excel work book 
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString);

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

conn.Open();
DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string sheetName = dtSheet.Rows[0]["table_name"].ToString();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" + sheetName + "]";
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);

using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    using(SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
    {
        //Give your Destination table name 
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "TABLE NAME IN SQL";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

How can I insert the data from all the sheets?

Comment: where are you actually having an issue?

Comment: Thanks Dispersia, Actually I have one excel with multiple sheets in tabs,  so need to insert data in sql server in multiple tables , one tab - one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it - you just need to iterate through each row in the tables table :

```
    ...
    DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

    // iterate each sheet
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow sheet in dtSheet.Rows)
    {
        string sheetName = sheet["table_name"].ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" + sheetName + "]";
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
            {
                // Give your Destination table name.  Table name is sheet name minus any $
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = sheetName.Replace("$", "");
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really helped but the loop is picking only one worksheet(tab) from access and not moving to next tab to execute same process.,Kindly help me

Comment: Try removing the conn,Close() from the inner using statement - that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks a lot now  working , one more help like I have a RowID autogenerated column in databse table but not in excel , so how can I add that also from code

Comment: Either don't use SqlBulkCopy and use your own SQL to create/update the table, or issue a ALTER TABLE ADD command via a SqlCommand after copying the table to add a column to it.